# Angular 2 table renders slow

Tags: angular

We have a data table component and it renders pretty slow in IE 11. It is pretty decent in Chrome. However our main browser is IE 11 so it should work fast in IE 11.

When I ran the "UI responsive" profiler in IE 11, the biggest cuprit was DomEvent when loading or sorting the table. It has lot of appendChild, insertBefore statements for td, tr tags and it takes around 8 seconds of just these DOM manipulations (screenshot below). In Chrome it takes around 2s which is acceptable.

[image: IE 11 profile]

I went through a few blogs of angular 1.x where they explained how to optimize a table with lot of entries and tried them in angular 2 but no luck so far in IE 11.

I was wondering if there is a way to ***compile all the rows and just insert them together*** rather than inserting one row after another.

I created a plunkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/Wqh6RLwT6IP8ijoIpr4a?p=preview) which also shows the same amount of DOM events in IE 11 profiler report when loading.

Any other suggestions will also be helpful.

```js
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="loadTable()" class="btn btn-primary">Load</button>
    <table class="table">
      <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  items = [];
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;
  }
  
  loadTable() {
    this.items = this.getItems();
  }
  
  private getItems() {
    let items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
      items.push({ 'id': i, 'name': 'Name' + i })
    }
    return items;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Did you try to change the changeDetection to OnPush?

Answer (score 6):

The only way you can improve performance whatsoever is by using `trackBy` option:

```
<button (click)="loadTable()" class="btn btn-primary">Load</button>
<table class="table">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIndex">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And in your component:

```
trackByIndex(index) {
    return index;
}
```

You can read more about `trackBy` [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html). If it's worth anything, I suggest using [PrimeNG's datatable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable) or [ngx-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable) because they have built-in pagination and they are really easy to implement, I don't see the point of doing this the way you are currently doing it.

Comment: Thanks I should have been more clear. The original prod code, does have the trackBy.

We did check the primeng datatable. The problem was our table has some crazy application specific UX behavior, we could not use it.

I will check the ngx-datatable and see if that will work for our scenario.